# $rootScope returns the value in it but function where i call it is not working (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am working with with Angular, NodeJs and Mongo (fairly new with all three) and I am trying to build a resource planning tool. The basic idea is that a user clicks on a main div (grid) and then a tile (=task) gets created where the user inputs some data. This tile is draggable and droppable and it snaps to the grid. The logic of the grid is based upon row and columns.

Now on I have a list of users on the left of the screen in a sidebar and i need to link/assign the task to the right users (so basically the tasks of that specific user).

So far I was able to determine the position of the user in the list (y position). And now i basically just have to compare the email of the $rootScope.users to that of the $scope.taskInfo and if there is a match I have to set the top value of the $scope.taskInfo equal to that of the $rootScope.users offsetTop, so that the tasks will show on the correct row.

Here is a visual of my application -> http://gyazo.com/539abe727f0c77be39ac85ee46f4c395, as you kan see it now just shows the tiles random on the grid

Part of my html code:

```
 <!-- START SIDEBAR -->
    <div id="sidebar" class="md-whiteframe-z4">
      <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="" >
      <div class="userList">
        <li ng-repeat="user in userInfo" id="userPos" class="circular" style="top: {{ user.top }}">
          <p class="initials" id="userValue">
              <custom email="user.email"></custom>
              {{user.initials}}
          </p>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR -->

    <!-- START CONTENT -->
    <div  ce-box-creator id="grid"  style="width: {{gridSizeNG.x * 122}}px;" ng-init="createGridLines()" class="containerContent" >
      <div class="todayHighlight" style="width: {{gridSizeNG.x}}px; left: {{(diffDays - 3)  * diffDays}}px;">

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- START TILE -->
    <div  class="tile contentEditorBox" ng-dblclick="showPopUp($event); setId( task._id )" ce-drag ce-resize ng-repeat="task in taskInfo"
    style="top: {{ task.row * gridSizeNG.y+ gridSizeNG.minY}}px;
    left: {{ task.column * gridSizeNG.x + gridSizeNG.minX }}px;
    width: {{ gridSizeNG.x * task.width }}px;"
    ng-data-id="{{ task._id }}" ng-init="snapInit()" ng-model="updateGridData" ng-row="{{ task.row }}" ng-column="{{ task.column }}" >
        <div class="txtWrapperTile">
        <div class="containerTxt" >
          <div class="taskName">
             <h4> {{ task.name }} </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="taskProjectClient">
            <p class="pPC"> {{ task.project_client_name}} </p>
          </div>
          <div class="taskLocation">
            <p class="pL">Location: {{ task.location }} </p>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <div class="taskEstimateTime">
           <div class="circle">
            <p class="pET"> {{ task.estimate_time }} h</p>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- end containerTxt -->
        </div><!-- end txtWrapperTile -->
    </div><!-- end tile contentEditiorBox -->
      <!-- END TILE -->
    <!-- END CONTENT -->
```

Part of my app.js:

```
//Custom directive 
    $rootScope = {};
        $rootScope.users = [];

        contentEditor.directive('custom', function($document) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: { email: '=' },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {  
                    var mail = scope.email;
$rootScope.users.push({
                    "mail": mail,
                    "positionTop": element[0].offsetTop
                });
                    console.log("User email is: " + mail);
                    console.log("Y positon of a user circle " + element[0].offsetTop);
                }
            }
        });


    //Function to save details for a task
            $scope.save_task = function() {

                //console.log("save-task-shizzle", this);
                //console.log("sopceingo", $scope.taskInfo);
                var url;

                console.log(editId);

                if(editId){
                    url = 'api/task/update/'+ editId;
                }else{
                    url = 'api/task/create';
                }

                console.log("URL URL USA", url, editId, $scope.start_time);

                var defaultStart = new Date();
                var defaultStart = defaultStart.getFullYear()+"-"+(defaultStart.getMonth()+1)+"-"+defaultStart.getDate();
                        defaultStart += " 00:00:00";

                var defaultEnd = new Date().addDays(2);
                var defaultEnd = defaultEnd.getFullYear()+"-"+(defaultEnd.getMonth()+1)+"-"+defaultEnd.getDate();
                        defaultEnd += " 00:00:00";

                console.log(defaultStart , defaultEnd);

                $http.post(url,
                    {
                        'name'                   : $scope.task_name,
                        'project_id'             : $scope.task_project_type,
                        'location_id'            : $scope.task_location,
                        'estimate_time'          : $scope.task_estimate_time || 2,
                        'project_client_name'    : $scope.task_project_client_name,
                        'url'                    : $scope.task_url,
                        'resource_link'          : $scope.task_resource_link,
                        'notes'                  : $scope.task_notes,
                        'start_time'             : $scope.start_time || defaultStart,
                        'end_time'               : $scope.end_time || defaultEnd
                    },
                    {
                        headers: {
                                "Content-Type":"text/plain"
                            }
                    }
                )

                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    //$scope.userInfo.push(data);
                    //$scope.get_task(); //this will fetch latest record from DB
                    getTaskFunction(
                      /* success function */
                      function(data) {
                          // $scope.taskInfo.push(data);
                          console.log("The tasks have been reloaded");

                      },
                      /* error function */
                      function()
                      {
                          console.log("Server load failed");
                      }
                    );
                  //    console.log("The task has been added successfully to the DB");
                    console.log(data);

                    $scope.taskInfo.push(data);

                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("Failed to add the task to DB");
                });
            }

//Function to retrieve the task info
var getTaskFunction = function(successFn, errorFn)
        {
              // original implementation of $scope.get_user but with success & error used which as passed in as parameter.
              $http.get('/api/task/all') // call the server

              .success(function(data) { // upon success
                  successFn(data); // call the function passed into the "getUserFunction" with the data from the server
                  //console.log("Retrieved task data from server");
                  //console.log("logging data: " , data);

                  $scope.updateGridDataAwesome();
                  //console.log("Barts test 1 ->", $scope.taskInfo);
                  //$scope.linkTaskToUser(data);
              })
              .error(errorFn || function() {
                  console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
              }) // process failure
          };

          this.reloadTaskList = function() {
          getTaskFunction(
              /* success function */
              function(data) {
                  //debugger;
                  $scope.taskInfo = data;
                  $scope.linkTaskToUser(data);
              },
              /* error function */
              function()
              {
                console.log("Server load failed");
              }
            )
        };

        // load list on startup
        this.reloadTaskList();

//Retrieving the users
        $scope.getUsers = function() {
            $http.get('/api/users').success(function(data)
            {
                $scope.userInfo = data;

                //console.log("Retrieved users from the server", data);
                //k$scope.createRowPerUser(data);
                //console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
            {
                console.log("Error in retrieving users from server");
            });
        }
        $scope.getUsers();
```

And this last bit of code loops first through all the users then through all the tasks and then it will check the email and if its a match it will set the top value of $scope.taskInfo equal to that of $rootScope.users offsetTop.

```
//Creating a row per user
        $scope.linkTaskToUser = function() {
            console.log("Logging root scope ", $rootScope);

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.taskInfo.length; i++) { //Doorlopen van alle taken

                    console.log('111111');
                for (var j = 0; j < $rootScope.users.length; j++) { //Doorlopen van alle users
                    console.log('fasfsda');
                    if ($rootScope.users[j].email == $scope.taskInfo[i].email) {
                        console.log('fasfsda1111'); //Vergelijken van emails tussen taken en users
                        $scope.taskInfo[i].top = $rootScope.users[j].offsetTop; //Top waarde van de taak gelijkstellen aan de offset van de user
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    $scope.createRowPerUser();
```

The problems is that when i run the application in the browser i don't see anything happening (the tiles are not assigning to the correct user in the row). So I am not sure if my code is right ... Any help is welcome

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: You're declaring a bunch of functions on a `$scope` that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.  Is there a controller definition missing from your code sample?  Or do those maybe want to be inside your directive instead?